# Empty cells are moving around when empty

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I have a problem with my style sheet that I am using to create the page menu bar. Whenever a page does not have previous or next page the cell is empty and the CSS only applies a background image. Whenever I try to implement this solution the cells that make up the menu bar are moved around and everything is no longer aligned. I need help to try and figure out how I can fix this issue.

[image]

The following is the class that has been applied to the empty cell that is shown in the image as the grayed out back button.

```
td.menu-back-disabled {
    background-image: url('back_first.png');
    display: block;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 85px;    
}
li.menu-bar {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: url('top.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This the html for the menu bar:

```
<table class="menu">
<br>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=environment" class="menu-home">
</a>
</td>
<td class="menu-edit-selected">
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=upload&number=1&filter=1" class="menu-upload">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=comments" class="menu-comments">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=log&number=1" class="menu-log">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=stats&number=1" class="menu-stats">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=settings" class="menu-settings">
</a>
</td>
<td class="menu-bar">
</td>
<td class="menu-bar-right">
</td>
<td class="menu-back-disabled">
</td>
<td>
<a href="https://peter-larsens-macbook.local:8081/cgi-bin/display?page=edit&number=2&filter=1" class="menu-next">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your empty cells have `&nbsp;` in them to be placeholders.

Also, try to avoid tables...

**Edit:**

Here is how my table looks at the moment. There should never be a place where the table will wrap to a new line since it's only one column and `width:100%;`

**CSS:**

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu {
            width:100%;
        }
        #menu td {
            text-align:center;
        }
        .menu-bar {
            width:30%;
        }
    </style>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="menu">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="menu-home">Home</a>
            </td>
            <td class="menu-edit-selected">
                <a href="#" class="menu-home">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="menu-upload">Upload</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <a href="#" class="menu-comments">Comments</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="menu-log">Log</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="menu-stats">Statistics</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="menu-settings">Settings</a>
            </td>
            <td class="menu-bar">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="menu-bar-right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="menu-back-disabled">
                <a href="#" class="menu-next">Back</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="menu-next">Next</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Any changes from this are probably from padding, margins or set widths. The `td.menu-bar` and/or `td.menu-bar-right` cannot be set to `width:100%;` because it would mean the entire width of the table/row, not the cell.

Comment: Thanks, for your input i have tried to build the menu not using tables and it is looking great except for the gray spacer at the end which i have previously set to width 100%. Now this will go to the next line. In other words i am not able to keep all the elements on the same line. Any thoughts on how to keep the grey spacer on the same line when its width is set to 100%?

Comment: Does the spacer at the end have a fixed or dynamic width?

Comment: It is dynamic. I have added the CSS class for the spacer above.

Comment: I copied the HTML table to my editor and I noticed the text for the links are missing. Also, there is a `<br>` inside your `<table>`, any reason why?